# Getting a facebook group's feed using koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rubygems, koala

I am trying to get the facbeook API to work.  I am using Koala, OmniAuth-Facebook, and Devise.  I am trying to get the feed from a facebook group.  I can get the posts of the facebook account, but I just get [] from the facebook group's feed.

```
#posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  require 'koala'  
def home

  end

 def index
   @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new('EAAEsRUgaygUBAGrJm9af4NAroK2zafwoVjtl9czVVqvfEDlLq2VV8LQChtBDHmrqQTS3119cSz8u1rEv4LrF5wXKIHC4CJGgUY8yiCQumYzLaDRTELTaj7vzQV9tZAuFDy5GQVYRnspIv17sGIFZA2uVkIZB2I5vLFaI0OFQQkdidT9lho75IfhkRk7xM6pLKB8KkwXTBsZBs4rbi8YXfkebI2yNVyHHRFH5p6u8NgZDZD')

 end

end`
```

and

```
#index.html.erb

<%= @graph.get_connection('me', 'posts', {
limit: 5,
fields: ['message', 'id']}) %>

<%= @graph.get_connection('14117761406', 'feed', {
limit: 5,
fields: ['message', 'id']}) %>
```

The first block prints out: [{"message"=>"test 1", "id"=>"106211743505945_106214170172369"}]

But the second block just prints [].

Comment: do you manage the group? is the group public?

Comment: group is public.

Answer (score 0):

you should do some R&D in console (`rails c`) then write your code. It will help you figure what happen to object, inspect them ...

Also check out `pry` gem

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
I was using get_connection instead of get_object, so it was trying to get a list of things I was posting in that group (nothing).

```
<%= @graph.get_object('14117761406?fields=feed.limit(10)') %>
```

this code works.

Second, when using test users, feeds in groups don't show up.  So even though I tested get_object before, it wasn't working with the test users.  I switched to my profile and it is working now.